# How to prevent Pod/Container from overwriting directories existing a PVC volume when it scales

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, persistent-volumes

I have a container image that stores files on /var/www/app by default. Once the app is up and running, updates to that directory are made, the PVC storage volume retains the changes with its reclaim policy. The problem here is, when the pod/container scales or recycles, the new pod wipes out the /var/www/app path stored on the PVC volume and resets the app or the PVC volume is mounted in a way that the container overwrites the mount.
Ive tried issuing
hostPath:
path: /var/www/app
type: DirectoryOrCreate

Thinking that the container wont overwrite the PVC directory if it detects files in that path but somehow I believe because the container image itself has /var/www/app existing with files in that path, the PVC volume never has a chance to mount and overwrite it with persisted changes, seems the container is overwriting the entire path everytime it deploys a new pod.

Comment: Perhaps you should show the code that your app uses to write to the volume? I would not recommend hostPath-volumes for apps unless you run on Minikube. Its hard to tell what you really want to do? Do you really want that multiple replicas of your app should share the volume? what access mode do you use, ReadwriteMany?

Comment: I narrowed it down, my persisted volume is not persisting files or folders when a pod dies. I am on EKS, my PVC is created with no issues, the mount appears in my container, I touch a file on /pvc-mount and kill the pod/container, another comes up and wala the file is missing. Ive tried 2 different storage classes, both GP2 and EBS-SC, Ive also tried 2 diffferent write types for the mount, ReadWriteOnce and ReadWriteMany but no matter what those files dont persist.

Comment: The container's image is not wiping anything out because the mount that gets created by the PVC/PV is not even referenced in my container image.

Comment: Ive also set my reclaim policy to retain.

Comment: Can you post your `Deployment`-manifest to show how the PVC is mounted in your pods.